# Effective approach to defining language-specific entities in EF code first

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, localization, code-first

I am developing a multi-lingual ASP.NET web application that makes use of Entity Framework Code First for data persistance. For example I have defined an entity for my "Project" instance

```
public class Project
{     
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Descr {get; set;}    
}
```

Now I want to add another language support, to allow admins to save different string data for different-language project description. Right now I have to just go ahead and add properties like

```
public string Name_Es {get; set;} 
public string Descr_Es {get; set;}
```

and provide a specific logic to allow population of these language-specific fields.

Is there a more efficient way to allow saving of language-specific data via EF Code First?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we did a project project which has slimier acquirement.   The Entities were like this,

```
   public class Project
    {     
        public Guid Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Descr {get; set;}   
        publis List<Translation>  NameTranslations{get;set;}
    }

    public Translation
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public int LanguageId {get;set;}
      public string Text{get;set;}
    }
```

And on top of the EF layer we can use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map our domain object with a specific language to a DTO. So the Dto doesn't have all the language translations. We had a static variable that has the current language Id(Enum) and depend on that Automapper will select the correct translation from NameTranslations list.

```
   public class ProjectDto
    {     
        public Guid Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Descr {get; set;}   
    }
```

The advantage of this method than yours is we don't need to have columns for each and every language  for each required columns. And if you want to add new language it's just adding new enum value and no changes for the domain objects.